# Spring-Drools Integration: Referenced file (kie-spring.xsd) contains errors

Tags: spring, xsd, integration, drools

I'm trying to use drools with Spring.
Spring version 4.01
Drools/Kie version 6.0.1

My kie-context.xml has the following error (in Eclipse):

> Referenced file contains errors (http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."

kie-context.xml: (imported in applicationContext.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <kie:kmodule id="ng-rule-server">
        <kie:kbase name="kbase1" packages="org.drools.server">
            <kie:ksession name="ksession1" type="stateless" />
        </kie:kbase>
    </kie:kmodule>

    <bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Relevant pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>${kie.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
        <version>${kie.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${kie.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<kie.version>6.0.1.Final</kie.version>            
<drools.version>6.0.1.Final</drools.version>
```

Details:
[image]

Can anybody see what's wrong with my set up?

Comment: Pretty sure that StackOverflow is for questions and answers. Not raising bugs. If you want to raise a bug with Drools, put it here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS

Comment: @Steve The intent was not to raise a bug, it is a genuine question. I have changed the last line to be more of a query than a statement.

Comment: @kmansoor Did you get any solution? me too facing the same issue

Comment: There are quite a few who have this issue - it's a Drools Spring thing not a bug tracker thing ...

Answer (score 3):

The right location can also be referred to by using the `classpath` : URL handler

`xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"`
`xsi:schemaLocation="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring classpath:org/kie/spring/kie-spring-6.0.0.xsd"`

Answer (score 2):

I skipped that error pointing xsi:schemaLocation directly to github address.

You can find it here: https://raw.github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/master/kie-spring/src/main/resources/org/kie/spring/kie-spring-6.0.0.xsd

In kie-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring
    https://raw.github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/master/kie-spring/src/main/resources/org/kie/spring/kie-spring-6.0.0.xsd">

<kie:kmodule id="sample_module">
    <kie:kbase name="kbase1">
        <kie:ksession name="ksession1" />
    </kie:kbase>
</kie:kmodule>
<bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Is not the good way, but works. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in eclipse with Spring 3.2.8 and Drools 6.0.0.Final. 
And during application startup it used to fail with below error:

> Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Drools - JBoss Community'.

After using kie-spring dependency, above problem got resolved.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${org.drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Voting down as the original post already mentions the suggested <dependency>.