# Drools-Spring MVC Integration | Failed to read schema document | No declaration can be found for element 'kie:kmodule'

Tags: spring-mvc, xsd, drools, kie

I am trying to do a POC to integrate Spring MVC with Drools.

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file tries to read the kie-spring.xsd file .

The [file location](http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd) on drools website gives 404.As a result the schema is not accessible and it gives warning as below.

"WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 35; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not ."

The above warning seems to result in error at line 25 .I the file it shows error as "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'kie:kmodule'."
When Below is the error::

"SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 25 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 35; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'kie:kmodule'."

I found the same issue mentioned in another Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635401/spring-drools-integration-referenced-file-kie-spring-xsd-contains-errors).
However the two solutions mentioned for it did not resolve the issue.

Below is the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml::

```
    <beans
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kiespring.mvc.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="kieUtil" class="org.kie.spring.KieSpringUtil"/>

  <kie:kmodule id="sample_module">
    <kie:kbase name="kbase1" packages="org.drools.spring.sample"/>
  </kie:kmodule>

  <bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kie.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-springmvc</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kie-springmvc Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <kie.spring.version>6.0.1.FINAL</kie.spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${kie.spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>kie-springmvc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have made changes in settings.xml for http in my maven installation global and user settings.

Any feedback or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google for a suitable kie-spring.xsd. E.g:

github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-spring/src/main/resources/org/kie/spring/kie-spring-6.0.0.xsd

Copy it to a location you can control. Change the URL.

Comment: I have copied it to one of the folders under my user. However now i get the error "SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring]" .I checked and found that kie-spring jar is present on my build path.

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue by hosting the file on my local machine . Accepting your answer.